# WHERE Clause in a complex MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which works fine.

But I now need to add a WHERE clause to it but I cannot figure out how and where I should place my WHERE clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) max_streak 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev = ms_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
            , @prev:=ms_date  
         FROM 
            ( SELECT DISTINCT ms_date FROM TABLE_NAME ORDER BY ms_date) x
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
     ) a  
 GROUP 
    BY i 
 ORDER 
    BY max_streak DESC
```

Could someone please advice on this?

**EDIT:**

In `TABLE_NAME` I have a `userEmail` column.

I need to run the entire query above `WHERE userEmail='some-email@email.com'`

I hope that makes sense better now.

Comment: You have a query with a subquery, which itself has two subqueries. Which one do you want to add conditions to?

Comment: @rickdenhaan, the main one. I will edit my question to explain this further.

Comment: This query isn't doing anything with `MY_TABLE`. If you mean `TABLE_NAME`, I suggest adding it to the query where you select the distinct `ms_date`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your WHERE as usually after FROM definition:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) max_streak 
 FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev = ms_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
            , @prev:=ms_date  
         FROM 
            ( SELECT DISTINCT ms_date FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE TABLE_NAME.userEmail='some-email@email.com' ORDER BY ms_date) x
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
     ) a  
 GROUP 
    BY i 
 ORDER 
    BY max_streak DESC
```

But sometimes its better to pick your fileds from internal subselect to filter with WHERE outside whole final query result.